# Swift - How to inherit from a custom cell that's tied to a xib file

Tags: swift, inheritance, cell, xib, nib

I have a custom cell called *NormalImageCell* that inherits from *UITableViewCell* and is tied to a xib. Let's say I wanted to create a new cell called *LargeImageCell* that inherits from *NormalImageCell* without creating a whole new xib. I can do this easily programmatically without interface builder, but due to *NormalImageCell* being tied to a xib and the cell in the xib can only be connected to one custom class and one reuseIdentifier, how would I be able to reuse it for LargeImageCell?

This works without Interface Builder.

`class LargeImageCell: NormalImageCell {...}`

```
tableView.registerClass(NormalImageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: NormalImageCell.id())
tableView.registerClass(LargeImageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: LargeImageCell.id())
```

This crashes with Interface Builder:

```
tableView.registerNib(NormalImageCell.nib(), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: NormalImageCell.id())
tableView.registerNib(LargeImageCell.nib(), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: LargeImageCell.id())
```

BTW, I'm declaring the nib and id methods like this:

```
class NormalImageCell: UITableViewCell {

    class func id() -> String {
        return String(self)
    }

    class func nib() -> UINib { 
        return UINib(nibName: String(self), bundle: nil) 
    }
}

class LargeImageCell: NormalmageCell {
    ...
}
```

Comment: How do you declared your `nib` methods?

Comment: class func nib() -> UINib { return UINib(nibName: String(self), bundle: nil) }

Comment: Do you have both nib files in your project: NormalImageCell.xib and LargeImageCell.xib ?

Comment: I only have NormalImageCell.xib. I don't want to create another xib for LargeImageCell because the two cells are nearly identical with only difference in in imageView size. I'm trying to reuse NormalImageCell by inheriting it so I don't have to duplicate any xibs/code.

Comment: _I don't want to create another xib for LargeImageCell_ Then you cannot do it.

Comment: Nib files include CustomClass definition for objects. If you want to instantiate a `LargeImageCell`, you need to have a nib file having `LargeImageCell` as a CustomClass definition.

Comment: Ok, so let's say I added a xib for `LargeImageCell`. Is there anyway I could avoid duplicating another cell in the xib and reuse the one from `NormalImageCell`'s xib instead?

Comment: No way, as far as I know. No need to discuss.

Comment: I'm not denying there may be some way to do what you want. I'm just saying I cannot contribute to find it.

Comment: @JosephLau Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

you should retrieve the nib from the main bundle like :

```
class func nib() -> UINib {     

   return UINib(nibName: String(self), bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So there is a solution to this, but it does complicate your datasource a bit.

1. Create your object `LargeImageCell` but don't give it any subtype.
2. In the initializer add `NormalImageCell` as a parameter along with any other info.
3. Configure the `NormalImageCell` and set it has a property on your object.
4. In your datasource, dequeue a `NormalImageCell` and initialize your object `LargeImageCell` with it.
5. Return the newly configured cell.

Not the best alternative but it works for extended functionality on a nib cell.